# enumerate append error while creating list from csv

Tags: python, list, append, enumerate

I'm stuck in a process of creating list of columns. I tried to avoid using `defaultdict`.

Thanks for any help!

Here is my code:

```
# Read CSV file
with open('input.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    #-----------#
    row_list = []
    column_list = []
    year = []
    suburb = []
    for each in reader:
        row_list = row_list + [each]
        year = year + [each[0]]#create list of years
        suburb = suburb + [each[2]]#create list of suburb
        for (i,v) in enumerate(each[3:-1]):
            column_list[i].append(v)
            #print i,v
    #print column_list[0]
```

My error message:

> ```
>  19         suburb = suburb + [each[2]]#create list of suburb
>  20         for i,v in enumerate(each[3:-1]):
>  ---> 21             column_list[i].append(v)
>  22             #print i,v
>  23 #print column_list[0]
>
>  IndexError: list index out of range
> ```

printed result of (i,v):

```
0 10027
1 14513
2 3896
3 23362
4 77966
5 5817
6 24699
7 9805
8 62692
9 33466
10 38792
0 0
1 122
2 0
3 
4 137
5 0
6 0
7 
8 
9 77
10
```

Basically, I want to have lists to look like this.

```
column[0]=['10027','0']
column[1]=['14513','122']
```

A sample of my csv file:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ly32U.png)

Comment: I don't understand how your output relates to your input.

Comment: @DanielRoseman My (i,v) did print out and have value. However,it's unable to append in 'column_list'

Comment: could you give a sample of the csv file you are trying to read ?

Comment: @sumit I have just updated a screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes Like Alex mentioned the problem is indeed due to trying to access the index before creating/initializing it as an alternative solution you can also consider this.

```
for (i,v) in enumerate(each[3:-1]):
            if len(column_list) < i+1:
                column_list.append([])
            column_list[i].append(v)
```

hope It may Help !

Comment: Yes! It did help. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

The error happens because `column_list` is empty and so you can't access `column_list[i]` because it doesn't exist. It doesn't matter that you want to append to it because you can't append to something nonexistent, and appending doesn't create it from scratch.

`column_list = defaultdict(list)` would indeed solve this but since you don't want to do that, the simplest is to make sure that `column_list` starts out with plenty of empty lists to append to. Like this:

```
column_list = [[] for _ in range(size)]
```

where `size` is the number of columns, the length of `each[3:-1]`, which is apparently 11 according to your output.

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation. I realise the mistake now:)